# How to close inputStream used by 2 threads

Tags: java, sockets, stream

I have 2 threads - one is to receiving messages and second is both for receiving and sending.

```
PrintStream os = new PrintStream(sock.getOutputStream());
BufferedReader is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));

ServerThread server = new ServerThread(sock, maxid, os,is);
OutputThread out = new OutputThread(sock, maxid, os,is);
```

Then, when I close connection I want to close is and os properly, but how to do it both in 2 threads? I get `java.net.SocketException` in `ServerThread`

```
public ServerThread(..){
    try{
          //here I use is and os

} finally {
        disconnect();
    }
}

public void disconnect() {
    try {
        System.out.println(addr.getHostName()+ " disconnected");
        os.close();
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } finally {
        this.interrupt();
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the code where you're trying to close them

Comment: First of all, move close() method to the finally block.

Comment: "one is to receiving messages and second is both for receiving and sending". Then you already have much more of a problem than you presently realize. You have *zero control* over which thread receives what. You must revise this architecture. It cannot work, at least not without very elaborate synchronization between the two threads, which would be much easier to achieve with a single reading thread and an internal queue. Possibly you don't need the reading-only thread at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your threads are recieving the is and os from external sources and hence the responsibility of closing the streams should lie with the external entity. Do not close them inside the threads. Handle it externally in the place where they are created.

Answer (score 0):

Look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html
This can be used for threads to wait for each other before one of them close the stream.